# Tornado URL regex: presence of a specific word into a keyword argument

Tags: python, regex, tornado

Trying to have a URL like this:

```
r"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/?**town**?/?$" (currently wrong)
```

where I want to be able to check if the user provided "town" in the endpoint after the name.
How can I pass this info to the request handler with a kwarg (only when its spelled correctly) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of this part: `/?**town**?/?`

Comment: what do you mean with "only when its spelled correctly"?

Answer (score 5):

Tornado allows multiple rules to specify the same handler class; this is often simpler than trying to construct complex regexes with optional pieces (especially when you want to make the trailing slash optional as well):

```
(r"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/(?P<town>[\w-]+)/?", MyHandler),
(r"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/?", MyHandler),
```

I think a combined regex would look something like this. Note the use of a non-capturing group `(?: )` to make the `/town` portion optional (but if it is present then the slash that separates name and town must be there too):

```
(r"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)(?:/(?P<town>[\w-]+))?/?", MyHandler),
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your needs, but how about:

```
"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)(?:/town)?/?$
```

Where `(?:/town)?` is a non capture group that makes the litteral `/town` optional.

Answer (score 0):

In what language is that regex? Eitherway you should be able to solve this if you just add a capture group and check if its empty

```
r"/person/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/((?**town**?)|())/?$"
```

Now it either saves a town or a emtpy string

Comment: Getting the following: "error groups in url regexes must either be all named or all positional" and the language is python with tornado framework

Comment: Seems like python groups are just indexes check if Group(0) is emtpy now (means no town was given) if it isnt emtpy then a town was given